# how can I scroll panel by keyboard input?JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have a panel and want to scroll it by entering **UP**/**DOWN**/**RIGHT**/**LEFT** arrow keyboard. 
I've already used `JScrollPane` but don't want to see the scrollbars, just want scrollable panel by entering keyboard.

Comment: Refer this may help you. and try to google properly. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604133/java-how-to-set-the-keyboard-scroll-speed-for-a-jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604133/java-how-to-set-the-keyboard-scroll-speed-for-a-jscrollpane)

Answer (score 0):

> don't want to see the scrollbars

```
pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
```

Don't attempt to play with the preferred size of the component.

Instead, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting the ScrollBar Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollbars). This is a property of the JScrollPane that you can set.